# React: how to execute two functions at the same time when one is dependent on the other

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i have a collabsable sidebar that i'm building with react and some menus have dropdowns, what would be the best approch to collapse the dropdown menus when the sidebar itself is called to collapse
i have to boolean's for the sidebar and the menus within the sidebar

this is the basic function that collapses the sidebar

```
const [open, setOpen] = useState(false) //for the menus
const [collapse, setCollapse] = useState(false) //for the sidebar


  function handleCollapse() {
    setCollapse(!collapse);
   }
```

i'm calling the function from a button `onClick={handleCollapse}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see 2 ways

1. Change your state to object

```
const [state, setState] = useState({ open: false, collapsed: false })

function handleCollapse() {
   if (!state.collapsed) {
     setState({ open: false, collapsed: true });
   } else {
     setState({ open: true, collapsed: false });
   }
}
```

2. `useReducer` with a similar functionality as useState

I would avoid `useEffect` - it would require state update twice.

Comment: how can i use this with a ternary operator?

Comment: setState(sate.collapsed ? { open: true, collapsed: false } : { open: false, collapsed: true })

Answer (score 2):

Just add an effect that gets triggered when collapse changes

```
useEffect(() => {
  if(collapse) setOpen(false)
}, [collapse])
```

---

btw, you can use functional state update to access previous `collapse`:

```
function handleCollapse() {
  setCollapse(prevCollapse => !prevCollapse);
}
```

Comment: this requires me to double click the  button

Comment: @redietyosef that shouldn't be the case. Maybe you need to adjust the conditions based on your application's logic.